# SQL Query Error ( although weird Query)

Tags: mysql

Well please check the query

Here table name is web18sso_login_a so

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%eb18ssoa%'
```

returns web18ssoa

userid is the Column in that table

now i want to get the data from the User ID with the query

```
select userid from (
    SELECT * from (
        select * from (
            select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name='web18ssoa'
        ) As bbc
    ) As ccv
) as nnn
```

the above Query says invalid userid from field list

i know i can directly use select userid from web18ssoa;

but i want to do via above query is there any other way without calling actual table getting column data from a table name

Please help me

Comment: Is there any reason you need this kind of hideous construct?

Comment: Yes it part of my project i am doing

Answer (score 1):

This is how your query construct is going to work, building up from the inner query towards the outer query:

inner query:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name='web18ssoa'

+------------+
| table_name |
+------------+
| web18ssoa  |
+------------+
```

This resultset gets aliased to `bbc`. You then do a `select * from bbc`, and alias that to `ccv`, then do a `select username from nnn`. Note that there is no "username" field in the original query result, which is why you're getting a no-such field. You're not querying the 'web18ssoa' table. You're querying a resultset which contains a row that happens have the value web18ssoa.

You cannot build a virtual query set like this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are under impression that the query selects from `web18ssoa`. In fact it does not. It ends up querying `information_schema.tables`. To do what you want, you need to build a dynamic query by using [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: Cant we do without using Prepare Statements ?

Comment: @subhashdasyam, NO not unless you want to step outside of (My)SQL.